# JPA Memory Management Issues

Tags: java, sql, jpa, memory-management, persistence

First, a little background. I am working on Management Software that pulls data from an SQL Server. I am using `JPA` to create `Entity` instances of the tables for manipulation within the management software (I've only been using `JPA` for a couple of days now). As a test, I threw together the below code to test how much memory would be taken up storing objects of their most abundant table (PeriodicalTable) which has 18,500 rows (or there abouts) and is only likely to grow;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceDemoPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM PeriodicalTable p");
    //query.setMaxResults(7000);
    List<PeriodicalTable> results = query.getResultList();
    PeriodicalTable storedPlayer;

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){
        storedPlayer = results.get(i);
        System.out.println(storedPlayer.toString());
        if (i == (results.size()-1)){System.out.println("Total results: "+(i+1)); }
    }

    em.close();
    emf.close();   
}
```

The above code throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` even though I have raised -Xmx to 512m. I don't want to use any more memory because the computers this software will be running on only have roughly 2GB of RAM. Now, I could use `.setMaxResults()` against each query (as you can see commented out), but that's not ideal because I will need to display all of them in the final product.

So, the question. Are there any more memory efficient methods of running toString on every Entity in a table, whilst using JPA? What are the pros and cons of these different methods? I had thought about maybe only storing a list of the String values passed by `.toString()` but can't think of a way of doing that without first using `.getResultList()` and storing the results in a list first.

Edit: As a side, I am using Java Standard JPA and haven't looked into Hibernate or ObjectDB or anything like that. Unless their use is essential I intend to avoid learning about more technologies than is necessary.

Comment: Can you please show your toString() implementation for PeriodicalTable.

Comment: Might help - reading page by page: http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Comment: @Rob Blake - `public String toString() {return reference;}` reference is just a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try paginating the results with `query.setMaxResults()` and `query.setFirstResult()`. That way you can load the results in chunks of for example 2500 rows.

Comment: does `.setFirstResult()` use the row number, or primary ID? The primary IDs for this table are all over the place (I didn't set it up myself).

Comment: Can you order the results by anything unique? Do that and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Well the primary ID is unique, but there are lots of gaps, but jumps between numbers, numbers of different lengths etc etc. Which is all fine I suppose, it will just make any logic difficult to orientate.

Comment: It won't matter to the JPA pagination mechanism. It doesn't paginate according to the ids, but row numbers.

Comment: Got it working with less than 512m memory now. Thanks. Now I just need to cut the loading times down, which are at 40 seconds for all 18000 results. Whoever created their previous management software managed to have all 18000 load almost instantly, so I have a little way to go yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, ORM's are not proper to load and handle large amounts of data. No matter how efficient your implementation is, ORM will use so much memory and CPU as they are highly relying on reflection. As you may see in their documentations, they are designed for Load-Modify-Persist scenarios. If you need to load and show large amount of data, you definitely will need pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the PeriodicalTable mappings and lazy load objects.

Comment: The Entity classes I have so far have no associated Entity objects to fetch. If that's what you mean. Otherwise I am afraid I will require some clarification on your answer.