# Load database values to Combo box - JSP, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I'm developing a web application using hibernate framework. I'm using JSP for the viewing purpose. There i need to load specific data from the database table into a combo box.
In this case i need to load all the role ids from ROLE table to a combo box
My code is as below.

```
 <tr>
                    <th align="left"> Role ID </th>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Combobox to get role id's -->

                        <%
                            try {
                                SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
                                Session s = sf.openSession();
                                Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

                                Role se = new Role();

                                String hql = "select ROLEID from EAD.ROLE";
                                Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
                                ArrayList li = (ArrayList) q.list();
                                Iterator ie = li.iterator();
                                int size = li.size();
                        %>  

                        <select>   
                            <%
                                while (ie.hasNext()) {
                                    Integer un = se.getRoleid();
                            %>

                            <option value="<%= un%>"><%= un%></option>

                            <%
                                }
                            %>
                        </select>   
                        <%
                            } catch (HibernateException he) {
                                he.printStackTrace();
                    }%>    

                        <!-- end of combobox-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Role.java

```
public class Role implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int roleid;
    private String title;
    private String rolename;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(int roleid, String title, String rolename) {
        this.roleid = roleid;
        this.title = title;
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }

    public int getRoleid() {
        return this.roleid;
    }

    public void setRoleid(int roleid) {
        this.roleid = roleid;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return this.rolename;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String rolename) {
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }

}
```

My problem is even the combo box is not displaying in the page. Any idea to fix this?? If can, please suggest solutions as soon as possible. Thanks :)

Comment: can you format the source code. what is the IDE using?

Comment: Im using netbeans IDE

Comment: Check ArrayList size if list size is 0 then no value is  set for select option. if any exception occurred  before <select> tag then combo box will not show in page.

Comment: select code in netbeans and press Ctrl+Shift+F to format code. then edit the post replacing edited code.

Comment: additionally are you getting an error message in console?

Comment: @developerbhuwan bt how can i check the size o ArrayList. I'm new to jsp and stuff :)

Comment: @Channa No error messages in console. Do you want me to paste the whole code in this specific class???

Comment: To check list size in your example : int size = li.size();

Comment: Can you test this code outside of jsp and see the results?

Comment: @developerbhuwan Thanx for the help!! Nothing displayed for the ArrayList size

Comment: @user2953113 i'll try. Thanx

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni I've edited the code :)

Comment: show me your entity class

Comment: You have `Role se = new Role();` and then `Integer un = se.getRoleid();`

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni Ive added the entity class. (Role.java)

Comment: @user2953113 yes.. and is that the problem??

Comment: Try `String hql = "FROM Role";` and in the while loop add `Role se = (Role)ie.next();` as first line.

Comment: @user2953113 above code didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it to show option,

Query : `"select r.roleid from Role r"`;

**Note:** if list have no element or size is zero then no option values will show in combo box

replace following code inside `<td></td>` :

```
<center>   
    <select>  
        <%
            try {
                SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
                Session s = sf.openSession();
                Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

                Role se = new Role();

                String hql = "select r.roleid from Role r";
                Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
                ArrayList li = (ArrayList) q.list();
                System.out.println("List Size = " + li.size());
                /*
                    if List Size is 0 then no option values will show
                */
                Iterator ie = li.iterator();
        %>

        <%
            while (ie.hasNext()) {
                Integer un = se.getRoleid();
        %>

        <option value="<%= un%>"><%= un%></option>

        <%
            }
        %>

        <%
            } catch (Exception he) {
                he.printStackTrace();
            }
        %>
    </select>   
</center>
```

Comment: using "select r.roleid from Role r" gave me a java heap exception. so i've changed the query to "select r.ROLEID from EAD.ROLE r" . And now the combo box is displaying and no values are loaded. any idea??

Comment: Console out put of List Size = is what 0 or other ?

Comment: No console output is displayed :( but there is a GlassFish server message saying "SEVERE:   org.hibernate.QueryException: undefined alias: ROLEID [select ROLEID from ROLE]"

Comment: you need to be aliasing the class, and then referring back to it in the column: Role is class and its alias let r. Then Query : "select r.roleid from Role r"

Comment: when i put that query, I get a Java heap space error. :(

Comment: If HQL query give java heap exception that means it is memory issue see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508271/jpa-memory-management-issues

Comment: There are only 5 rows available

Comment: do you use glassfish ?

Comment: stop glassfish server then run application in netbeans